# Loading files through goog.require in a script block fails

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

When using `goog.require` inside a `<script>` tag to load a script, the specified files aren't loaded. For example:

```
<script>
goog.require('goog.dom');
var mydiv = goog.dom.$('foo');
</script>
```

Gives:

```
goog.dom is undefined
```

What's wrong with this usage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `goog.require` dynamically adds the required script tags to the document *after* the current script tag. So, for example:

```
<script>
goog.require('stuff');

doSomething();
</script>
```

Translates to:

```
<script>
goog.require('stuff');

doSomething();
</script>
<script src=[included stuff] type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The solution is to have a separate script tag for requirements:

```
<script>
goog.require('stuff');
</script>

<script>
doSomething();
</script>
```