# Google closure: goog.require could not find: goog.ui

Tags: javascript, google-closure

I'm learning google closure, and when I try to use the `goog.ui` component (any class thereof), I get the error `goog.require could not find: goog.ui`.

My code is:

```
goog.require('goog.dom');
goog.require('goog.json');
goog.require('goog.events');
goog.require('goog.ui.HoverCard');
goog.require('goog.positioning.AnchoredPosition');
goog.require('goog.positioning.Corner');
goog.require('goog.ui.Component.EventType'); 
goog.require('goog.ui');
```

The other components (at least before I try to load any ui element) work just fine.

Any suggestions on what this could be? I have the version cloned from git about two days ago. I'm not compiling, because at this stage I just want to figure out how to write the code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `goog.require()` on elements that have been provided by a `goog.provide()` before.

`goog.ui` is never provided because it's not a component or something that you can use directly with "static" methods (Contrary to `goog.events` that has `listen()` methods for instance). 
It's just a naming convention to regroup all visual components.

However, you can do a `goog.require('goog.ui.Component')` or `goog.require('goog.ui.Button')` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to eliminate this by:

1. Loading the `base.js` file directly from google's git repository: `http://closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure/goog/base.js`;
2. Eliminating the attempt to require `'goog.ui'` separately from any subcomponent thereof; and
3. Moving the `require` calls into the HTML head directly (inside a script tag), rather than having them in a script loaded in the head.

This doesn't seem entirely satisfactory.

Comment: 1. Where were you loading base.js from before?
2. I think that's the important part. There is no `goog.provide('goog.ui');` anywhere, only provides of `goog.ui.Component`, etc.

Comment: @MatrixFrog I was loading from a local installation cloned from git, but via my webserver (i.e. I was hosting my own copy).

Comment: I believe you were running into [this documented problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732225/loading-files-through-goog-require-in-a-script-block-fails) in uncompiled mode. Make sure you have loaded `base.js` (and your deps, if they exist) as the first script src tags, then load your `goog.require` calls in their own script tag, and lastly your application code in another script tag.

Comment: @AlexLaertes Your comment is the most insightful thing on this page. I certainly am not compiling, you're quite right. If you want to work this up into an answer I will certainly accept it.

Comment: @Marcin I pass this onto you:) Your question had two parts: inability to require the `goog.ui` namespace (you don't, suggested by @JulCh) and you had to split your require calls from your application code (which you ultimately discovered; I just pointed you to the cause).